# How to enter data dynamically into matrix in R programming

Tags: r, arrays, function, matrix, statistics

I have a code to filter inconsistencies in data in R where i entered data manually. Help me in making it dynamic with the mentioned columns where i can input data during run time with n no. of rows.

```
bikers_inconsistent <- function(n){
x <- n[n$id!="NA" & n$age!="NA" & n$age>=18 & n$dl!="NA"& n$tr1!="NA" & n$tr2!="NA" &n$cases!="NA" & n$cases>=0,]
return(x)
}
id <- c(1:10)
age <- c(19,25,23,16,26,28,24,17,22,19)
dl <- c(3,5,2,3,4,7,3,4,1,1)
tr1 <- c("NA",380,798,800,390,120,870,712,210,510)
tr2 <- c(500,420,1502,1523,1308,"NA",1982,1923,420,0)
tr3 <- c(1114,112,2100,2104,1884,420,3100,2899,0,0)
cases <- c(0,2,2.3,3,-2,1,2,3,0,0)

bikers <- data.frame(id,age,dl,tr1,tr2,tr3,cases,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
print(bikers)
print(bikers_inconsistent(bikers))
```

Comment: What part of the current code you want to make dynamic?

Comment: @ronak
I want the data entry to be dynamic

Comment: It is not exactly clear to me still. Can you include couple of examples of how the dynamic function be called and it's expected output?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve - 
1. Prompt user to enter no. of rows of data 
2. Prompt user to enter row 1 data into respective columns
3. Store the data into a matrix

For ex: System shld ask me how many rows of data u want to enter
I will enter 8

Then system should ask me to enter data of row 1- name,id, roll no. , marks in science exam, marks in social exam
I will enter the values respectively 
Then system should ask me to enter row 2 and so on till row 8 and then should exit the loop
Then the data which i entered shld b stored into a matrix so that i can read & process it